# CodeIgniter Helper Error

Tags: php, codeigniter, syntax-error, codeigniter-3

I have written this code on helper to get a dynamic side bar but I get the following error:

> "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''"> Keuangan' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE) in C:\xampp\htdocs\SIAPWPRO\application\helpers\global_helper.php on line 47"

Here is my code:

```
<?php  if ( ! defined("BASEPATH")) exit("No direct script access allowed");
function generate_sidemenu()
{
    return '<li>
    <a href="'.site_url('').'"><i class="fa fa-dashboard fa-fw"></i> Dashboard</a>
</li>

<li>
    <i class="fa fa-edit fa-fw"></i> Data Administrasi
        <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
            <li>
                <a href="'.site_url('').'"> Tim</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="'.site_url('').'"> Karyawan</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="'.site_url('').'"> Pelanggan</a>
            </li>

     </ul>
</li>

<li>
    <i class="fa fa-star fa-fw"></i> Acara
        <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
            <li>
                <a href="'.site_url('').'"> Data Keseluruhan</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="'.site_url('').'"> Notifikasi</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="'.site_url('').'"> Pengeluaran</a> 
            </li>
        </ul>
</li>

<li>
    <i class="fa fa-book fa-fw"></i> Laporan

     <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
        <li>
            <a href="'.site_url('').'"> Progress Event</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="'.site_url('').'"> Keuangan</a>
        </li>
     </ul>
</li>;
}
```

Comment: just add  `'` at the last most li `</li>;
}'

Comment: Please replace : <a href="'.site_url('').'">  to <a href="'.site_url().'"> and try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

last `</li>; to </li>';` The lack of single quotes.

Comment: yes, that's right. i did the typo.